# How to show this particular $4 \times 4$ matrix is positive definite?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

I am preparing for an exam in Numerical Analysis, and I am solving some practice problems. The question is to show that the following matrix $A$ is positive definite. I would only have about 10 minutes to work on this problem, so I am trying to solve this as fast as possible.

We are also told that all the eigenvalues of $A$ are distinct (but this information may not be useful here; there is a part b to this question which might make use of this fact)

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 & 2 & 0\\
-1 & 4 & -1 & 1\\
2 & -1 & 6 & -2\\
0 & 1 & -2 & 4
\end{bmatrix}$$

**My Attempts:** My first tought is to use [Greshgorin's Circle Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem) to show that all the eigenvalues are positive. However, this does not work because  the first Greshgorin disk contains negative reals.

My second tought is to use [Sylvester's Criterion.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion) This is perhaps doable in under 10 minutes, but it is prone to mistakes (especially when going fast). I am also not sure if Sylvester's Criterion was taught in the class that this problem comes from.

Comment: Calculating the pivots maybe faster ??

Comment: The eigenvalues don't appear to have a nice closed form, and smallest eigenvalue is about $0.0216$. So finding the eigenvalues by inspection or using some clever approximation might be out of the question. The bottom-right 1x1, 2x2, and 3x3, submatrices are clearly diagonally dominant. Hence, these are positive definite, and thus, have a positive determinant. So your just left with showing the determinant of the entire 4x4 matrix is positive.

Comment: @2rd_7 Thanks for the suggestion, but what do you mean by calculating the pivots? Since this matrix is (presumably) invertible, the pivots are in the diagonal positions.

Comment: @JimmyK4542 Thanks for the response. Would you have any examples of a matrix where we can use some clever trick to prove it's positive definite? I ask because I am trying to gather more tools for the exam.

Comment: @Helix have a look at nosuchthingasmagic's answer

Comment: The fastest and the least error-prone way, I believe, is to kill all off-diagonal entries on the first row and the first column by $a_{11}$, and then apply Sylvester's criterion to the trailing $3\times3$ principal submatrix.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@2rd_7's suggestion to calculate the pivots seems quick and straightforward. You just need to keep subtracting out multiples of the remaining rows (i.e., add the first row to the second, subtract 2 times the first row from the third, etc.) until you get an upper triangluar matrix:
$U = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -1 & 2 & 0\\ 0 & 3 & 1 &1\\ 0 & 0 & 3 & -1\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 26/9\end{bmatrix}$.

The pivots are now on the diagonal and are all positive, so the matrix is positive definite.

Comment: From here are we using Sylvester's Criterion, or is there a more elementary way to conclude that the matrix is PD?

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

The rows from $2$ to $4$ are diagonally dominant. The first one is not. But we can make it so by multiplying on both sides by the matrix $\operatorname{diag}(t, 1, 1, 1)$, where $t$ is large.

$\bf{Added:}$ Looks plausible, but the other rows are affected. Indeed, need $t> 3$, and then the second row is not dominant anymore. So the solution is not good. In fact, one can check that there is no way to transform our matrix with a diagonal matrix to make it diagonally dominant.

Maybe just showing directly that the determinant is positive. Since the principal minor $(2,3,4)$ is positive definite, being dominant, this would be good enough.

Using [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7B1%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%7D%2C%20%7B-1%2C%201%2C%200%2C%200%7D%2C%20%7B2%2C%201%2F3%2C%201%2C%200%7D%2C%20%7B0%2C%201%2F3%2C%20-7%2F5%2C%201%7D%7D.%20DiagonalMatrix%5B%7B1%2C%203%2C5%2F3%2C%202%2F5%7D%5D.%7B%7B1%2C%20-1%2C%202%2C%200%7D%2C%20%7B0%2C%201%2C%201%2F3%2C%201%2F3%7D%2C%20%7B0%2C%200%2C%201%2C%20-7%2F5%7D%2C%20%7B0%2C%200%2C%200%2C%201%7D%7D), I got the [Cholesky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition#LDL_decomposition) decomposition of the matrix

$$\left[\begin{matrix} 1 & -1 & 2 & 0  \\ -1& 4 & -1& 1\\ 2& -1& 6&-2\\ 0&1 &-2&4\end{matrix} \right]=\\=\left[\begin{matrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\ -1& 1 & 0& 0\\ 2& 1/3 & 1&0\\ 0&1/3 &-7/5&1\end{matrix} \right]\left[\begin{matrix} 1 & 0& 0 & 0  \\ 0& 3 & 0& 0\\ 0& 0& 5/3&0\\ 0&0 &0&2/5\end{matrix} \right]\left[\begin{matrix} 1& -1& 2& 0\\ 0& 1& 1/3& 1/3\\ 0& 0& 1& -7/5\\0& 0& 0& 1\end{matrix} \right]$$

The diagonal part has moderate eigenvalues. Now, $A$ has a small eigenvalue, $\approx 0.02$, and this is possible since the upper diagonal part has a small singular value.

Comment: This is great thank you!

Comment: @Helix:  I am sorry, but the solution does not work, since the other rows are not affected. So we need another idea. Please remove the point and the accepted answer mark

Comment: Thank you very much for your attempt!